# What does "Liquid error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass" mean on a posterous blog?

Tags: posterous

I have faced an issue with this message on the right side of my blog. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this error too.  You're probably running a liquid filter on a value that is coming up nil.  I had something like this on my jekyll site:

```
<title>{{ page.title | xml_escape }}</title>
```

And on my root page, the title was not set.  You can fix it by making sure that the value is set, or you can hack around with with something like this to force the nil into a string:

```
{{ page.title | append:' ' | xml_escape }}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Typically, you want to check if `page.title` exists. A better solution would be `{% if page.title %} <title>{{ page.title | xml_escape }}</title>`