# Jekyll build fails with "Liquid Exception: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass" when using cgi_escape filter

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm using {{site.url | cgi_escape}} in my index.html file in a Jekyll 1.1.2 project. Whenever running a server, the build fails because of 
**Liquid Exception: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass**

On my other computer I have Jekyll 0.12.0 and the same project does build successfully.

What might be the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031229/what-does-liquid-error-private-method-gsub-called-for-nilnilclass-mean-on help? Is your site.url set?

Comment: Yup, site.url is set in _config and {{site.url}} renders properly as expected. The problem occurs only when cgi_escape filter is applied.

Since the problem is only on Jekyll 1.1.2 and not on 0.12.0 I guess it has to do with the jekyllversion or maybe Liquid version installed?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same error message when trying to apply the uri_escape filter to a page variable in the post layp

```
{{page.description | uri_escape}}
```

Turns out that not all of my posts had the description variable set in the yaml front matter.  Adding the description variable to all posts and re-running `jekyll build` sorted the problem.

Comment: I had a very similar problem caused by one of my posts not having an excerpt - it complained about `search.json`, but otherwise the error was the same. This was with Jekyll 3.1.2.